# Prove or disprove: $x^{p}+a$ is irreducible where $a\in \mathbb{Z}_{p}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

> Prove or disprove: $x^{p}+a$ is irreducible where $a\in \mathbb{Z}_{p}$.

This is what I've done so far:

By Fermat's Little Theorem, since $a^{p-1}\equiv 1$ (mod $p$) or $a^{p}\equiv a$ (mod $p$), then $x^{p}+a^{p}$ (mod $p$). Should I use Eisenstein's criterion on this polynomial? Any hints? I feel like this polynomial is reducible.

Comment: Consider $a=0$.

Comment: Hint: Assuming $p$ is prime, we have  $(x+a)^p =x^p+a^p$